# Cut event's end time in month view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have some problem with fullCalendar after update for newer version.
If event's end time is earlier than 9AM, then last day of the event will be cut.

My fullCalendar initialize:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
       left: 'prev,next today',
       center: 'title',
       right: ''
   },
    editable: false,
    events: [
        {
            "title":"normal 3 days event",
            "start":"2015-04-13T08:00:00",
            "end":"2015-04-15T09:00:00"},
        {
            "title":"cutted 3 days event",
            "start":"2015-04-19T01:00:00",
            "end":"2015-04-21T08:00:00"}],
    timeFormat: ' '//for hiding of event's start time
});
```

Also, I provide [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lap2a42r/) with 2 events. First has end time later than 8AM and work correctly, second is cut.

I thought trouble is with timezones and tried to add timezone: "UTC", but it won't help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That´s related with [nextDayThreshold](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/) and not with timezones.
By default, if a multiday event ends before 09:00 is not displayed. If you want to display every event, just set it to 00:00:00.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month, agendaWeek' //You can check it adding new views
            },
    editable: false,
    nextDayThreshold : "00:00:00", //Add this line
    events: [{"title":"New Franchisee Training","location":"Hastings, MN","start":"2015-05-11T08:00:00","end":"2015-05-15T11:00:00","color":""},{"title":"Vitals Training","location":"PL","start":"2015-05-19T01:00:00","end":"2015-05-21T05:00:00","color":""}],
                timeFormat: ' ',
            timezone: 'UTC'
});
```

I've fork your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9n8yurdp/). I added also buttons to different views, so you can check it easily.